# Please add a way to reorder top answers on Careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

When I first filled out my Careers profile, I picked and chose several answers to appear in the new Top Answers section. Now that I look at it again, there's another one or two which I would like to appear at the top. But the only way to have an answer appear higher is to remove the answers that are above it and then re-add them afterward.

Can we have little up and down arrows to reorder the answers?

> [image: excellent illustration with virtually lifelike art]

Comment: This was in our "Before LAUNCH" milestone and is now in the "After LAUNCH" milestone.  We'll get to it in the next couple days.

Comment: @Jason Punyon: Good to know, thanks. I figured you must have thought of it before.

Comment: -1, alt text should be "PEW PEW PEW LASERS"

Comment: @Daniel: No, that little guy has a *sling*. Get it?

Comment: oh wow *<headdesk>*  slings and arrows ... good thing I didn't *actually* -1 it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done now.  Let me know how it works (or doesn't :))