# Add the ability to add "top questions" to Careers 2.0 Profile

Tags: feature-request, questions, jobs

Allow me to add my own "top questions" too! I know, I know, the site should be more heavily weighted to answering, but sometimes, *how and what people ask is important too!* For example I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474514/use-of-or-as-branch-control-in-fp) which I think is a fairly good question. Clearly I'm going to avoid questions where I've asked something very simple, but I know of a user or two who are implementing their own C standard libraries and the depth of those questions is important/ought to be on show.

Of course, the argument *I can just look at their profile* holds, but that awesome q/a might have been from a year or so ago in which case finding it is difficult.

Comment: #1 exists here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81394/please-add-a-way-to-reorder-top-answers-on-careers  Could you turn this into a feature request for #2?

Answer (score 14):

This is a good idea because the most highly voted posts are rarely the ones I'm most proud of because my best ones are the most obscure. In fact, I'm almost ashamed of which ones have the most votes.

Now that I think about it, SO has the same problem: the most highly-voted questions on SO are also some of the worst.

Answer (score 9):

I really want this because the way people communicate when they're seeking help is relevant. I definitely think employers would want to see a post that showed a candidate's thought process and what their response was to not being able to fix something themselves.

Answer (score 1):

That's an awesome idea and a very much needed feature.

While answers are important, I don't consider questions to be less important. If you can express yourself clearly and create a clear and precise question, that's when you will get the best answers, so questions and answers are related.

This also shows a potential employer how an individual reacts when he doesn't know something (which is bound to happen in pretty much any job), so this gives a lot of information about the personality.

I'm answering this now even if this was requested a while ago as I think this is **the** most important feature request on Careers 2.0