# Allowing me to link to a SO question on my Careers 2.0 profile

Tags: feature-request, questions, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add the ability to add “top questions” to Careers 2.0 Profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85357/add-the-ability-to-add-top-questions-to-careers-2-0-profile)

Careers 2.0 allows me to add to my profile, an answer that I provided on SO. However, it doesn't allow me to link to **questions** I asked on SO. I would like to have this ability.