# Any way to tailor the "Top Answers" section on Careers?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Besides the ability to [reorder items](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81394/please-add-a-way-to-reorder-top-answers-on-careers) in the **Top Answers** section of Careers, it would also be quite helpful if there was a way to specify *how many* Top Answers to display. My profile page displays 7; I don't know if that is the universal default, but I would rather reduce that to maybe 3 or 4 so it has a less massive presence on the page.

(I realize that one has the option of removing answers from the section, but that fundamentally changes an automatic process to a manual one and would seem to open a whole can of worms I do not want to open, for example: Does deleting an entry change the number of answers in the list permanently? What happens when another answer gets enough votes for my list? What about if the answer I deleted gets a new vote--does it reappear? Is the list still populating automatically or do I now have to manage it manually? ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, actually...the management of which answers to show isn't automatic. When you first create your profile, we add your top 7 answers from Stack Overflow and that's the end of our involvement in choosing which answers to show.  So if you'd like fewer answers then you should delete some.

Comment: Wow--your reply is a genuine surprise! Because the Stack Exchange Account scores--**immediately** above the Top Answers--**are** automatically updated, this strongly suggests that the Top Answers are also. So I would like to revise my plea to be: _can you add a notice in the Top Answers section--in edit view--that the answers will never update automatically?_ Perhaps I should enter this as a separate MSO feature request...?

Comment: @msorens: Yes the scores are updated, but we don't mess with *which* accounts are shown.

Comment: I understand that, but the important point to glean here is that scores and answers are much more closely related than accounts and answers. So if scores are updated then--in the absence of any note to the contrary--many users will also assume that answers are.

Comment: @msorens the logic behind it is that we might keep the data within an element up to date, but we don't change which elements are shown on your profile.  So we keep your accounts up to date, but we don't change which accounts are shown, and we keep your answers up to date, but we don't change which answers are shown.  But I agree that this is not clear right now...